# Shopping Cart, 'Delete' input button doesn't work

Tags: php, cart

First, here we can see files index.php, cart.html.php and catalog.html.php

file index.php

```
<?php

$items = array(
  array("id" => '1', "name" => 'Meitantei Conan/Case Closed', "category" => "Comics & Manga", "desc" => "nodesc", "price" => '4'),
array("id" => '2', "name" => 'Harry Potter and the Philopher\'s stone', "category" => "Books", "desc" => "nodesc", "price" => '20'),
array("id" => '3', "name" => 'Harry Potter lol', "category" => "Lolling", "desc" => "nodesc", "price" => '20'),
array("id" => '4', "name" => 'My Harry Potter', "category" => "Junk", "desc" => "nodesc", "price" => '20'),);


session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {

      $_SESSION['cart'] = array();

}


if(isset($_POST['action']) && ($_POST['action']) == "Buy") {

  $_SESSION['cart'][] = $_POST['buyid'];
  header('Location .');
}

   if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'Empty Cart') {

    unset($_SESSION['cart']);
    header('Location: ?cart');
    exit();

}


if(isset($_GET['paypal'])) {

   echo "I will add here paypal and other things..";
   exit();
}

if(isset($_GET['cart'])) {

  $cart = array();
  $total = 0;

      foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id) {

            foreach($items as $product) {

                 if($product['id'] == $id) {

                    $cart[] = $product;
                    $total += $product['price'];
                    break;

                 }

            }

      }

      include 'cart.html.php';

      exit();

}


      if(isset($_POST['del']) && ($_POST['del']) == 'Delete') {

          if(isset($_GET['del'])) {

        $cart = array();
        $delid = $_POST['delid'];

      foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id) {

        foreach($items as $product) {

            if($product['id'] == $delid) {


                    unset($_SESSION['cart'][$delid]);

            }

        }




      }

      }

    }


   include 'catalog.html.php';
```

File catalog.html.php

```
      <?php                           
if(!isset($_COOKIE['visits'])) {

        $_COOKIE['visits'] = 0;

}

$visits = $_COOKIE['visits'] + 1;

setcookie('visits', $visits, time() + 3600 * 24 * 365);

?>

                                   <!DOCTYPE html>
                                     <html lang="it">
                                     <head><title>Products Catalog</title>

                                        <style>
                                           table {
                                              border-collapse: collapse;

                                          }

                                              td, th {

                                               border: 1px solid black;

                                              }


                                        </style>
                                     </head>
                                     <body>
                                      <?php global $visits;

                                      if($visits > 1) {

                                            echo "<h2>Welcome back!! Visit number: $visits</h2>";

                                      } 

                                      else echo "<h2>Welcome! This is your first visit!</h2>";

                                      ?>

                                      <p>Your cart contains <?php echo count($_SESSION['cart']); ?> items.</p>
                                      <p><a href="?cart">View your cart</a></p>
                                      <table border="1">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Item Name</th>
                                            <th>Item Desc</th>
                                            <th>Item Category</th>
                                            <th>Price</th>
                                            <th>Options</th>

                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <?php foreach($items as $item): ?>
                                       <tr>
                                        <td><?php echo $item['name']; ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $item['desc']; ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $item['category']; ?></td>
                                        <td>$<?php echo number_format($item['price'], 2); ?></td>
                                        <td><form action="" method="post">
                                            <div>
                                                <input type="hidden" name="buyid" id="buyid" value="<?php echo $item['id']; ?>">
                                                <input type="hidden" name="price" id="price" value="<?php echo number_format($item['price'], 2); ?>">
                                                <input type="submit" name="action" id="action" value="Buy">
                                            </div>
                                        </form>
                                       </td>
                                   </tr>
                               <?php endforeach; ?>
                           </tbody>
                       </table>

                    </body>
                                     </html>
```

And then, file cart.html.php

```
    <?php                           
if(!isset($_COOKIE['visits'])) {

        $_COOKIE['visits'] = 0;

}

$visits = $_COOKIE['visits'] + 1;

setcookie('visits', $visits, time() + 3600 * 24 * 365);

?>
                                     <!DOCTYPE html>
                                     <html lang="it">
                                     <head><title>Cart</title>

                                        <style>
                                           table {
                                              border-collapse: collapse;

                                          }

                                              td, th {

                                               border: 1px solid black;

                                              }


                                        </style>
                                     </head>
                                     <body>
                                      <h1>Your cart</h1>
                                      <?php global $visits;

                                      if($visits > 1) {

                                            echo "<h2>Welcome back!! Visit number: $visits</h2>";

                                      } 

                                      else echo "<h2>Welcome! This is your first visit!</h2>";

                                      ?>
                                      <?php if(count($cart)>0): ?>
                                      <p>Your cart contains <?php echo count($cart); ?> items.</p>
                                      <p>Total: <?php echo number_format($total, 2); ?></p>
                                      <table border="1">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Item Name</th>
                                                <th>Item Desc</th>
                                                <th>Item Category</th>
                                                <th>Price</th>
                                                <th>Options</th>

                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tfoot>
                                          <tr>
                                            <td>Tot:</td>
                                            <td><?php echo number_format($total, 2); ?></td>
                                          </tr>
                                        </tfoot>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <?php foreach($cart as $item): ?>
                                       <tr>
                                        <td><?php echo $item['name']; ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $item['desc']; ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $item['category']; ?></td>
                                        <td>$<?php echo number_format($item['price'], 2); ?></td>
                                        <td><form action="?del" method="post">
                                            <div>
                                                <input type="hidden" name="delid" id="delid" value="<?php echo $item['id']; ?>">
                                            <input type="submit" name="del" id="del" value="Delete">
                                            </div>
                                        </form>
                                       </td>
                                   </tr>
                               <?php endforeach; ?>
                           </tbody>
                       </table>
                       <p><a href=".">Return back to our catalog!</a></p>
                       <form action="?" method="post">
                       <p><a href="?paypal">Continue shopping</a> or <input type="submit" name="action" id="action" value="Empty Cart"></p>
                    </form>
                   <?php else: ?>
                   <p>Your cart is empty! You can buy from our <a href=".">catalog</a></p>
                 <?php endif; ?>


                    </body>
                                     </html>
```

This script is in this website: http://hydrerscript.altervista.org/

In simple words, my test site, where I load all my scripts (PHP, JQuery and others...)

Anyway, what is the problem?

Well, the problem is which when we delete a item by 'Delete' button, system delete only items which are duplicates, triplicates (and so on..) of the others..

Simple example:

You can try to buy and put in your cart 8 items, 2 conan, 2 my harry potter, 2 harry potter and the philopher's stone and 2 harry potter lol, then go to view your cart.

This will be image showed:

Img -> http://dumpshare.net/images/1765764stackoverflow.PNG <- Img

Then, try tgo to your cart and click 'Delete' for each items.

As you will can see, system delete only until to 4 items, because, as I have written, are deleted only  items that are duplicates, triplicates and so go on, of the others..

Why?

How resolve it

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are mixing apples and pears.

When you add item to your cart

```
$_SESSION['cart'][] = $_POST['buyid'];
```

you add the id of the item you are buying to the end of array.
For example:
your cart is empty. You hit "buy" of item "my harry potter"
the array will look like this:

```
array(0 => '4');
```

now you hit "buy" for Conan:

```
array(0 => '4', 1 => '1');
```

etc...
the first number from 0 => '4' is autoincremented index while the second is your product id.

if you want to delete and item from the array, what you need is to pass your index not the id of a product. So in the example above, if you want to delete "my harry potter" you do not pass '4' into the hidden field but '0'

in your cart.html.php

change this

```
<?php foreach($cart as $item): ?>
```

to this

```
<?php foreach($cart as $index => $item): ?>
```

and this

```
<input type="hidden" name="delid" id="delid" value="<?php echo $item['id']; ?>">
```

to this

```
<input type="hidden" name="delid" id="delid" value="<?php echo $index; ?>">
```

in index.php
This code

```
    foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id) {

        foreach($items as $product) {

            if($product['id'] == $delid) {


                unset($_SESSION['cart'][$delid]);

            }

        }

   }
```

then shrinks to

```
unset($_SESSION['cart'][$delid]);
```

only

Btw. in case your cart will be manipulated by more than one script, you should also change this in your index.php

```
if(isset($_GET['cart'])) {

  $cart = array();
  $total = 0;

      foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id) {

            foreach($items as $product) {

                 if($product['id'] == $id) {

                    $cart[] = $product;
                    $total += $product['price'];
                    break;

                 }

            }

      }

      include 'cart.html.php';

      exit();

}
```

syncing indexes like this

```
if(isset($_GET['cart'])) {

  $cart = array();
  $total = 0;

      foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $index => $id) {

            foreach($items as $product) {

                 if($product['id'] == $id) {

                    $cart[$index] = $product;
                    $total += $product['price'];
                    break;

                 }

            }

      }

      include 'cart.html.php';

      exit();

}
```

note, please, that i didn't look for any other mistakes in your code